# Jupyter notebook (on remote server) to run in background and keep printoutput

Tags: background, output, jupyter-notebook, remote-server

I am running a Jupyter notebook on a remote server (AWS). Some of the task take quite a while, so I want to do the following:

1. Whenever I start the Jupyter notebook, the printoutput from each code line is gone, or even as if I start a complete new session and have to run each code again to get the respective results: How I can keep the results / output below each line? So other people can see the code and directly the result without rerunning it (i.e. they don't have access to my server)? I have seen jupyter notebook pages where code and results are available on GitHub etc, but couldn't find a description on actually doing it, especially when run on a remote server.
2. Type my code in the line, hit run and in case it takes too long or I know it will take long, close the browser and even disconnect from the server - while keeping 1. intact: So far I understand that with 'nohup jupyter notebook' I can keep the jupyter notebook running although I disconnect from the server - AWS server is still running of course.

Thank you.